# Aligning products in WooCommerce WordPress plugin

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, alignment

I'm using the WooCommerce plugin for WordPress, but I can't seem to get my products aligned right. When images are different sizes, the product names and prices aren't aligned. How can I fix this? It needs to be a pure CSS solution.

HTML:

```
<ul class="products">
  <li class="product">
    <a href="http://renservice.dk/produkt/hmk-m529-reparationssaet-marmor/">
            '<img width="246" height="300" src="http://renservice.dk/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/HMK-M529-Reparationssæt-til-marmor-246x300.jpg">
        <h3>HMK M541 Plejesæt til natursten</h3>
        <span class="price">
                <span class="amount">363,75&nbsp;DKK</span>
          <small class="woocommerce-price-suffix">inkl. moms
                    <span class="amount">291,00&nbsp;DKK</span>
                </small>
            </span>
        </a>
  </li>
  <li class="product">
    <a href="http://renservice.dk/produkt/hmk-m541-plejesaet-til-natursten/">
      <img width="300" height="268" src="https://www.natursteinpflege24.de/media/image/22/cc/9a/HMK-M541-Naturstein-Pflegeset564dbdd087b73.jpg">
      <h3>HMK M541 Plejesæt til natursten</h3>
      <span class="price">
                <span class="amount">363,75&nbsp;DKK</span>
      <small class="woocommerce-price-suffix">inkl. moms
                    <span class="amount">291,00&nbsp;DKK</span>
                </small>
      </span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="product">
    <a href="http://renservice.dk/produkt/hmk-p301-3-i-1/">
      <img width="131" height="300" src="http://renservice.dk/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/HMK-P301-3-i-1-131x300.jpg">
      <h3>HMK P301 3-i-1</h3>
      <span class="price">
            <span class="amount">178,13&nbsp;DKK</span>
      <small class="woocommerce-price-suffix">inkl. moms
            <span class="amount">142,50&nbsp;DKK</span>
                </small>
      </span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul.products {
  margin: 0 0 1em;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  clear: both;
  display: block;
  -webkit-margin-before: 1em;
  -webkit-margin-after: 1em;
  -webkit-margin-start: 0px;
  -webkit-margin-end: 0px;
  -webkit-padding-start: 40px;
}

ul.products::before,
ul.products::after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}

ul.products li.product {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 3.8% 2.992em 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 22.05%;
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
  display: list-item;
  color: #141412;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 100%;
}

ul.products li.product a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ca3c08;
}

ul.products li.product a img {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 0 1em;
  box-shadow: none;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

ul.products li.product a h3 {
  padding: .5em 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-family: "arial black", arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: -0.070em;
  line-height: 1.3;
  color: #333333;
  display: block;
  -webkit-margin-before: 1em;
  -webkit-margin-after: 1em;
  -webkit-margin-start: 0px;
  -webkit-margin-end: 0px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

ul.products li.product a .price {
  color: #77a464;
  display: block;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-bottom: .5em;
  font-size: .857em;
  visibility: collapse;
}

ul.products li.product a .price .amount {
  visibility: visible;
}

ul.products li.product a .price .woocommerce-price-suffix {
  visibility: visible;
}

ul.products li.product a .price .woocommerce-price-suffix .amount {
  display: inline;
  white-space: pre;
  color: #CCCCCC;
  visibility: visible;
}

ul.products li.product a .price .woocommerce-price-suffix .amount::before {
  content: '\A(' !important;
}

ul.products li.product a .price .woocommerce-price-suffix .amount::after {
  content: ' ekskl. moms)';
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zs3Lrg10/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your images are variable in size, you can specify a fixed height value for all the images and set width to auto:

```
ul.products li.product a img {
  ...
  height: 150px;
  width: auto;
  ....
}
```

**Updated solution**

There are two steps which need to be considered.

Use flexbox and align product items `flex-end` which will position the items at the bottom of the container. Also

```
ul.products {
  ...
  /*display: block */;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap; /* allow items to be flowed on multiple lines */
  align-items: flex-end;
}
```

After this update, it is easily seen that the producs name and prices still are not correctly aligned because some names might span over 2 or more rows. For this you could specifying a `min-height` value for the header tags:

```
ul.products li.product a h3 {
  ...
  min-height: 40px;
}
```

In order to maintain the alignment for smaller viewports, you could use javascript to calculate the `min-height` based on the height of the heighest header tag. Hopefully I explained clear enough.

Please see **updated** [fiddle](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PZOwEQ).

Comment: Yeah, but that means that some images will either be too wide or become distorted if I set `max-width: 100%;`

Comment: can you give an example for this? please update fiddle with this scenario

Comment: I don't know how to update and save the fiddle, but if you change img width to 300 px in stead of 150px, you'll see that the middle image is now 336px wide. I need it to be no more than 300px wide like its container. If I set ´max-width: 100%;´ or ´max-width: 300px;´, the image will be distorted.

Comment: @JeppeBech I have updated my aswer. Let me know if this suites you better.

Comment: Thanks, this works better than my own solution, because the images aligne at bottom and not top. Thank you for taking time to help me out :-)

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution myself. Added this to the CSS:

```
ul.products li.product a {
    height: 425px;
    display: block;
}
ul.products li.product a h3 {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
}
ul.products li.product a .price {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Seems to work :-)